# How to insert linebreak every 40 characters with Regex?

Tags: regex, abap

I want to insert line breaks in a very long string using `REPLACE ALL OCCURENCES OF REGEX`.
Unfortunately it does not work. It inserts the line break only one time at the very beginning then does nothing with the remaining string.

```
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ` &&#adipiscing elit. Proin sagittis tortor at
```

Here is my program.

```
REPORT zzz.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(gv_string) =
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ` &&
`adipiscing elit. Proin sagittis tortor a` &&
`t bibendum eleifend. Cras nisi felis, ac` &&
`cumsan vitae euismod eget, viverra sed i` &&
`psum. Integer imperdiet eleifend interdu` &&
`m. Nunc sed ultrices lectus. Sed nisi ex` &&
`, tincidunt quis arcu eget, commodo temp` &&
`or odio. In hac habitasse platea dictums` &&
`t. Nunc sit amet convallis ex, in conseq` &&
`uat velit. In suscipit orci lectus, laor` &&
`eet pretium leo molestie non. Duis trist` &&
`ique ipsum non porta faucibus. Nullam ia` &&
`culis rutrum arcu, sit amet rhoncus mass` &&
`a interdum at. Donec luctus magna metus,` &&
` et varius massa euismod vel. Nunc sem s` &&
`em, lobortis et convallis nec, aliquam e` &&
`u nunc. Nullam quis sollicitudin ante. N` &&
`ulla suscipit eu ante lobortis sodales. ` &&
`Cras mattis enim a leo pellentesque, ut ` &&
`interdum orci rutrum. Fusce varius matti` &&
`s pulvinar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ` &&
`consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mol` &&
`estie ipsum et aliquam porttitor. Phasel` &&
`lus consectetur viverra sem. Aenean cons` &&
`equat eros eget rutrum tempus. Aliquam e` &&
`rat volutpat.`.

REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX `^.{40}` IN gv_string WITH '`$0` &&\n'.
BREAK-POINT.
```

The regular expression `^.{40}` and the replacement string I use are for sure correct, because I get the result I want for example in Notepad++.

Is this some kind of a bug or is this documented somewhere as a constraint in ABAP-RegEx?

Comment: Do you want to insert a line break every 40 characters? Remove the ^ from the regex expression: '.{40}'

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai You are absolutely right! If you post your comment as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: I did, btw, whenever I want to torture myself with regex, I use this site https://regex101.com/ - it analyses the regex expression and gives explanations

Comment: TIL regex101.com. Thanks @JózsefSzikszai for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the ^ from the regex expression, to insert a line break every 40 characters:

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX `.{40}` IN gv_string WITH '`$0` &&\n'.
```